# mqty looks ugly due to bad vertical spacing

Tags: matrices, line-spacing

Below is a snippet of my code:

`12: We can rewrite $W$ as $s\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0]+t\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]$. Again we assume that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that $W=$ Span$\left\{\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0],\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]\right\}$. Since both vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ since they have 4 entries each, by theorem 1 the given set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.`

Here's how the code looks:

[image]

I identified two reasons why it looks bad:

1. The vertical spacing between entries are excessive
2. The vertical spacing of each line is based solely on the maximum height of the line instead of where that occurs.

How can I make it look better?

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 9in}]{geometry}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ii}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\jj}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"11}
\newcommand{\ih}{\mathbf {\hat{\ii}}}
\newcommand{\jh}{\mathbf {\hat{\jj}}}
\newcommand{\kh}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{k}}}}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{+ .1\textheight}
```

Comment: always show a complete small  document that produces the output you show, the spacing looks excessive but is due to code you have no shown so it is hard to help, but even if you reduce the spacing setting vertical arrays in inline text is never going to look reasonable.

Comment: If you really need these four-column-vectors in inline formulas, I recommend you to use row vectors, transposed.

Comment: Please tell us how or where `\mqty` is defined.

Comment: I see that `\mqty` is used in the `physics` package. I have many doubts on its usefulness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how `\mqty{1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0}` is easier to type or at least clearer than

```
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
```

I would keep at arm's distance from `physics`, but you're to judge whether to follow my recommendation.

Anyway, after just fixing the “Span” problem, I typeset the following example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\begin{document}

12: We can rewrite $W$ as $s\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0]+t\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]$. 
Again we assume that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that 
$W=\Span\left\{\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0],\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]\right\}$. 
Since both vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ since they have 4 entries each, by 
theorem 1 the given set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

\end{document}
```

and got

[image]

No spacing problem in the matrices. What's the problem? That you probably use `setspace` or directly some `\linespread` instruction. Indeed, if I add `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\doublespacing` to the above code, I get

[image]

It's a known problem with double spacing. Fix `\arraystretch` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}% the reciprocal of 1.667

\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\begin{document}

12: We can rewrite $W$ as $s\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0]+t\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]$.
Again we assume that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that
$W=\Span\left\{\mqty[1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0],\mqty[3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 4]\right\}$.
Since both vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ since they have 4 entries each, by
theorem 1 the given set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, some notes are in order:

1. don't use double spacing unless it's imposed by your institution;
2. don't use big matrices inline: transpose them and give symbolic names.

Comment: Can you please explain more about why I should avoid using the `physics` package? And can you please explain more about why I should not use double spacing? Perhaps because my previous teachers requires double spacing in word documents that I become used to the look.

Comment: I self-learned latex through Google (need-based questions) so I probably made some questionable choices.

Comment: @JoyJin `physics` commands have weird syntax and in several cases they make hard to type simple things. The implementation is very awkward, to say the least. About double spacing: take any book off your shelf or any research journal; how many of them use double spacing?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you (a) transpose the vectors when they're used in inline math mode and (b) not hesitate to use display math mode. E.g.:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\begin{document}

\noindent
12. We can rewrite $W$ as 
$s\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}'
+t\begin{bmatrix}3 &-1 &-1 & 4\end{bmatrix}'$,
where $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that 
\[
W=\Span\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}     1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 3 \\-1 \\-1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix*}
\right\}. 
\]
Since both vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (since they have 4 entries each), by Theorem~1 the given set is a subspace of~$\mathbb{R}^4\vphantom{\big]'}$.
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

TeX is unable to calculate the line spacing relative to the postion of large object in the lines. It doesn't know, if the large object are one above to second or (as in your example) these large objects don't touch if the space between lines is reduced. TeX works with lines as with boxes with its height and depth. The height is given as maximal height of objects in the line and depth analogically. When TeX inserts space between lines, it looks only to depth and height of the lines, no to depth and height of all objects inside the lines individually.

Best solution of your problem is presented by Mico: use transposition of vectors in the in-line math. Or, you can use smaller size of matrices in the in-line math. OpTeX does this automatically:

```
\def\mqty[#1]{\left[\matrix{#1}\right]}
\hsize=17cm \parindent=0pt

12: We can rewrite $W$ as $s\mqty[1\cr 1\cr 2\cr 0]+t\mqty[3\cr -1\cr -1\cr 4]$.
Again we assume that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that $W=$
Span$\left\{\mqty[1\cr 1\cr 2\cr 0],\mqty[3\cr -1\cr -1\cr 4]\right\}$.
Since both vectors are in ${\bbchar R}^4$ since they have 4 entries each, by
theorem 1 the given set is a subspace of ${\bbchar R}^4$.

\bye
```

gives

[image: mqty1]

You can reduce the individual space between lines by `\vadjust` TeX primitive too. Our example:

```
\def\mqty[#1]{\left[\matrix{#1}\right]}
\hsize=17cm \parindent=0pt

12: We can rewrite $W$ as $s\mqty[1\cr 1\cr 2\cr 0]+t\mqty[3\cr -1\cr -1\cr 4]$.
\vadjust{\kern-9pt}%
Again we assume that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers. This shows that $W=$
Span$\left\{\mqty[1\cr 1\cr 2\cr 0],\mqty[3\cr -1\cr -1\cr 4]\right\}$.
Since both vectors are in ${\bbchar R}^4$ since they have 4 entries each, by
theorem 1 the given set is a subspace of ${\bbchar R}^4$.

\bye
```

gives

[image: mqty2]